# Get only the name of a DataFrame - Python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export

I'm actually working on a ETL project with crappy data I'm trying to get right.
For this, I'm trying to create a function that would take the names of my DFs and export them to CSV files that would be easy for me to deal with in Power BI.

I've started with a function that will take my DFs and clean the dates:

```py
df_liste = []
def facture(x) : 
    x = pd.DataFrame(x)
    for s in x.columns.values :
        if s.__contains__("Fact") :
            x.rename(columns= {s : 'periode_facture'}, inplace = True) 
    x['periode_facture'] = x[['periode_facture']].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%Y%m'))
```

If I don't set 'x' as a DataFrame, it doesn't work but that's not my problem.

As you can see, I have set a list variable which I would like to increment with the names of the DFs, and the names only. Unfortunately, after a lot of tries, I haven't succeeded yet so... There it is, my first question on Stack ever!

Just in case, this is the first version of the function I would like to have:

```py
def export(x) :
    for df in x :
        df.to_csv(f'{df}.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: DataFrames don't have names

Comment: you can put them into the dictionary and set the dict key  as preferred name of the df

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to set the name of your dataframe first using `df.name` (probably, when you are creating them / reading data into them)

Then you can access the name like a normal attribute

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( data=[1, 2, 3])
df.name = 'my df'
```

and can use

```
df.to_csv(f'{df.name}.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```